# Proof determinant and trace of transformation matrix of an endomorphism regarding different bases depend on the choice of the bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, solution-verification

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rk}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$

I would be happy if someone could check this proof and tell me any mistakes I shall correct.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector-space with $\dim(V)>0$. Given an Endomorphism $g: V \to V$ we first want to show, that the determinant of the $n \times n$ transformation matrix $A$ regarding two different bases $v$ and $\tilde{v}$ of $V$ depends on the choice of the bases of $V$.

Let us assume that $\det(A)=\det(g)$ regardless of the choice of the bases of $V$ and let us fix $\det(A)=:r \neq \{0,1\}$.

Since $\det(A)\neq 0 \Rightarrow \rk(A)=n$ we know that we can find bases $w$ and $\tilde{w}$ of $V$ as well as invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that the $(n \times n)$ transformation matrix $A'$ regarding $w$ and $\tilde{w}$ is of the form $P^{-1}AQ=I_n=:A'$

Clearly, $\det(A')=\det(I_n)=1 \neq r = \det(A)$ which is a contradiction to the assumption that $\det(A)=\det(g)$ regardless of the choice of the bases of V.

So $\det(A)$ depends on the choice of the bases of $V$, what was to be shown.

Similarly let us assume, that $\tr(A)=\tr(g)$ regardless of the choice of the bases of $V$ and let us fix $\tr(A)=:t > n$. Again we can find bases $u$ and $\tilde{u}$ as well as invertible matrices R and S such that the $(n \times n)$ transformation matrix $\tilde{A}$ is of the form

$$R^{-1}AS= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & \cdots  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

We observe that $r$ = $\rk(\tilde{A})=\tr(\tilde{A})$. So clearly $\tr(\tilde{A}) =r \leq n \neq \tr(A) > n$ which is a contradiction to the assumption that $\tr(A)=\tr(g)$ regardless of the choice of the bases of $V$.

So $\tr(A)$ depends on the choice of the bases of $V$.

Comment: You need $\det A$ to be distinct from both $0$ and $1$. The claim is false over the $2$-element field $\mathbb{F}_2$ ! It is also false if $\dim V = 0$, but let's not be pedantic :)

Comment: For the trace, your argument requires a field of characteristic $>n$. I'm wondering how well that claim works for finite fields.

Comment: Other than this, it's a good proof. (But just to make sure, you should explain how to come up with a matrix whose trace is $>n$.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for your answer. I added $dim(V)>0$ and $det(A)\neq\{0,1\}$. I did understand, why this is important. You also mentioned the 2-element field $\mathbb{F}$ which we didn't learn until now in university so I don't think this will be a problem (at the moment  ;) ). So now the actual question with the field of charaterstics which I don't know. Isn't it sufficient to claim that we can find a matrix with $tr(A)>n$ since $A$ is a $(n$ x $n)$ matrix. If not, could you explain why it is important to mention and how I can explain how to come up with a matrix with $tr(A)>n$? Thanks!

Comment: It's easy to find a matrix with arbitrary trace, and it has nothing to do with $A$ being $n \times n$.

Comment: Is it sufficient to clarify that we surely can find a transformation matrix $A$ with $tr(A)>0$ e.g. the $(n$ x $n)$-diagonal matrix with all diagonal-entries $2$ instead of just fixing $tr(A)=:t>n$?

Comment: Note that usually, one calls trace and determinant independent of the choice of basis. What that means is that as long as we have $v = \tilde{v}$, both $det$ and $tr$ will not change no matter which basis $v$ you pick.

Comment: I am aware of that. In this case I just had to prove that if we pick two different bases $v$ and $\tilde{v}$ of $V$ it follows that the statemant, trace and determinant are independent of the choice of basis, in general, is wrong.